# Extjs4 - How to get value from the first record from a Store

Tags: json, get, extjs4, store

I am very new in Extjs4.

I have a store which takes from json?

```
Ext.onReady(function(){    
 var storePermissao = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ["bancos"],
    autoLoad: true,
    autodestroy: true,
    proxy: {
        type: "ajax",
        url: "ajax/permissoes.php",
        reader: {
            type: "json",
            root: "data"
        }
   }
});
```

This store takes just one record and one field (bancos) from my database.
How to read the value from the field bancos? I have tried:

```
Ext.getStore('storePermissao').loadData(data);    
var rec = Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('storePermissao').getAt(0);
```

I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'override' of undefined;

When I used the code bellow, I can see the result, but I can not use it.

```
 var permissaoUsuario =
    storePermissao.load({
        scope: this,
        callback: function(records,operation,success){
                if(success){
                    var req = storePermissao.first();
                    var teste = req.get('pbancos'); 
                    console.log('teste');
         }
    }
 });
 console.log('teste'); (it doesn't work!)
```

How can I get this value?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It looks like you need more understanding of javascript at all. But show us how the json response look like.

Answer (score 0):

If there is always one record why don't you use Model instead of store. Store is collection of model and in your case there is not collection but only one record. Below is same to load User model. More details can be found in docs http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Model

```
User.load(123, {
success: function(user) {
    console.log(user.getId()); //logs 123
}
```

});